# Is there a specific "Shaliach"?

Tags: words, passover-seder-hagada, text

In the haggadah, when the text comments on various verses, it discusses Hashem's taking the people out of Egypt, and explains that it was done

> לֹא עַל־יְדֵי מַלְאָךְ, וְלֹא עַל־יְדֵי שָׂרָף, וְלֹא עַל־יְדֵי שָׁלִיחַ

Not by means of an angel, and not through a Saraf and "not by the hand of (a) messenger/proxy" [my translation].

A few lines later, the text explicates

> ...אֲנִי וְלֹא שָׂרָף; וּבְכָל־אֱלֹהֵי מִצְרַיִם אֶעֱשֶׂה שְׁפָטִים. אֲנִי וְלֹא הַשָּׁלִיחַ;

I and no saraf...I and not THE messenger/proxy.

The text adds in a definite article, as if it is pointing to a specific messenger and not a generic idea of one (even though it continues to refer to the generic angel and saraf).

Is there some specific entity known as The Messenger and if so, why wouldn't the text refer to it consistently instead of shifting from the indefinite to the definite?

Comment: The Aruch HaShulchan in his Haggadah called Leil Shimurim picks up on the definite article you noticed. He suggests it's referring to the malach Metatron. I don't have time to write it up as an answer right now but maybe later. His Haggadah is on hebrewbooks. Hagadah Sheleimah brings this as well from the Ramban and Rashbatz